# Running command from cron not working with no error

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to create a method to change my desktop background randomly. I am using crontab to handle the change every 10 minutes.

The crontab

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/feh --recursive --randomize --bg-fill 
/home/aaron/Pictures/wallpapers/minimalist 2>&1
```

The syslog

```
syslog:Oct 20 09:20:01 skull-nuc CRON[19895]: (aaron) CMD (/usr/bin/feh --recursive --randomize --bg-fill /home/aaron/Pictures/wallpapers/minimalist 2>&1)
syslog:Oct 20 09:30:01 skull-nuc CRON[20449]: (aaron) CMD (/usr/bin/feh --recursive --randomize --bg-fill /home/aaron/Pictures/wallpapers/minimalist 2>&1)
```

Trouble shooting -

First I changed my shell to sh and tested the command. It works. I tested the command in bash. It works. I allow it to run from cron and nothing happens and no error is produced. It just runs every ten minutes and my background only changes when I do it manually.

I have verified

1. Script works alone
2. Script works from sh
3. cron service is running
4. cron is running the command with no discernable output
5. I am unsure what else to do

Comment: Perhaps tell it which shell to run: `/bin/sh /usr/bin/feh --recursive ...`  Also, how do you tell if there is output? Perhaps you should redirect to a file `2>&1 /some/file.log`

Comment: Oh. nm. I see `feh` is it's own program. Shell shouldn't matter. Not familiar with `feh`. Do you need to specify a file to output to or anything? How do you know there is no output when it's running through cron?

Comment: Does `feh` need the DISPLAY environment variable to be set, in order for it to connect to the correct X session to change its background?   DISPLAY is probably not set in the cron environment.

Comment: @JimLewis This solved my issue. You must set a display using export DISPLAY=:0 && before it will work. Would you like to turn this into an answer for me?

Comment: SuperUser has [a duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1033903/why-doesnt-cronjob-execute-feh-command) but I couldn't find one directly related to `feh` on SO. The [cron tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) has a stock explanation ready for copy&paste.

Comment: @ILikeTurtles: Glad it helped!  I've added the info as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cron environment will usually differ from the environment you have in an interactive shell.  In this case, you should check the DISPLAY environment variable, which many X utilities use to figure out which session to connect to.
If it's not set, `feh` will probably fail in just the way you described.

Missing environment variables can be set directly in the command line you're using in the crontab, or you can write a wrapper script that sets up the environment, then calls `feh`, and then call the wrapper from cron.